# Knowing whether a copyright infringement will demonetise or block on youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-monetization

I run a weekly pub quiz for a choir I'm in. We run it via youtube and google forms to make life easier for everybody but obviously media rounds cause a copyright problem.

Currently my strategy is to take all the video and audio clips I'm planning to use, upload them unlisted and then wait a day to see if they get blocked. If they do, I swap out for something else and try again until everything is either unflagged or just demonetised (there's never more than 200 people on it so monetisation really isn't an issue).

So the question is, is there an easy way to know if a song will result in a block or just demonetisation?